# C#: Selecting particular index values from a list

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to search a list that returns me an bunch of indexes based on a search i make on that list. For ex i have a comma separated string list as follows:

```
Blue, 3
Red, 3
Blue, 1
Blue, 9
Red, 5
```

I want to make a search that returns me indexes of all elements EXCEPT any that contain the text found in a criteria list. The criteria list could contain:

```
Blue, 3
Red, 5
```

So in pseudo code, it would be,

ColorList.SelectIndex(!Containing(Words found in all elements of criteriaList)

The above should return indexes 1,2,3

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
var indexes = ColorList.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
                       .Where(x => !criteriaList.Contains(x.Value))
                       .Select(x => x.Index);
```

If your lists contain many items then you *might* get better performance by converting `criteriaList` to a `HashSet<T>` first. (You'll need to benchmark to determine whether this is the better option in your case.)

```
var criteriaSet = new HashSet<string>(criteriaList);
var indexes = ColorList.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
                       .Where(x => !criteriaSet.Contains(x.Value))
                       .Select(x => x.Index);
```

Comment: oops: you are using the index on the filtered list? This will return 0,1,2 (test it)

Comment: This will search through the entire criteriaList at once with the statement criteriaList.Contains(x)? And will it return index integer values of the colorList?

Comment: @sehe, @KerryL: Oops! Fixed it now.

Comment: hmmmm yeah that looks a lot more like... erm... my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new []{"Blue, 3", "Red, 3", "Blue, 1", "Blue, 9", "Red, 5"};
var criteria = new []{"Blue, 3", "Red, 5"};

var filtered = list
        .Select((s,i)=>new {s,i})
        .Where(e => !criteria.Contains(e.s))
        .Select(e => e.i);
```

results: `{ 1, 2, 3 }`

Comment: what is e.s? what exactly is it doing?

Comment: it's using a little known overload (version) of the Select extension method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx. It is a 'counting' enumerator, you get two values (s,i): the string **_and_** the index

Answer (score 2):

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new List<string> {"Blue, 3", "Red, 3", "Blue, 1", "Blue, 9", "Red, 5"};

    var colorList = new List<string> {"Blue, 3", "Red, 5"};

    var indexes = data.Except(colorList).Select (x => data.IndexOf(x));

    indexes.Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may want to use a

```
 List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> pair = new KeyValuePair<string, int>
```

then you can do

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> p in pair){
    s = p.Key;
    i = p.Value;
}
```

to get the values

Comment: What is this solving? If you wanted that, simply do `list.Select((s,i)=>new{s,i}).ToDictionary(e=>e.i, e=>e.s)`; However, it adds _little_ over using `list[n]` directly.

Comment: My main point is that instead of storing the values in a list of strings, I believe it would be easier and less confusing to use a list of KeyValuePairs. Especially if you were planning on using this list for more than this search. But to each their own.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you want to achieve here, so perhaps my answer is not what you are looking for.

Anyway, in a generic list, you could use a lambda expression/ linq statement on your collection. Consider these examples I have written for you:

```
internal class ListLambdaLINQSample
{

    List<KeyValuePair<Colors, int>> listSource;
    List<KeyValuePair<Colors, int>> listCriteria;
    List<KeyValuePair<Colors, int>> listMatches;

    private const int COLORCODE1 = 1;
    private const int COLORCODE2 = 2;
    private const int COLORCODE3 = 3;
    private const int COLORCODE4 = 4;
    private const int COLORCODE5 = 5;

    internal enum Colors
    {
        Red, Blue, Green, Yellow
    }


    public ListLambdaLINQSample()
    {   // populate the list
        listSource = new List<KeyValuePair<Colors, int>>();
        listCriteria = new List<KeyValuePair<Colors, int>>();

        _populateListCriteria();
        _populateListSource();

        ...
    }

    private void _getMatchesWithLINQ()
    {
        listMatches =
                        (from kvpInList
                             in listSource
                         where !listCriteria.Contains(kvpInList)
                         select kvpInList).ToList();
    }

    private void _getMatchesWithLambda()
    {
        listMatches =
            listSource.Where(kvpInList => !listCriteria.Contains(kvpInList)).ToList();
    }


    private void _populateListSource()
    {
        listSource.Add(new KeyValuePair<Colors, int>(Colors.Blue, COLORCODE1));
        listSource.Add(new KeyValuePair<Colors, int>(Colors.Green, COLORCODE2));
        listSource.Add(new KeyValuePair<Colors, int>(Colors.Red, COLORCODE3));
        listSource.Add(new KeyValuePair<Colors, int>(Colors.Yellow, COLORCODE4));
    }

    private void _populateListCriteria()
    {
        listCriteria.Add(new KeyValuePair<Colors, int>(Colors.Blue, COLORCODE1));
        listCriteria.Add(new KeyValuePair<Colors, int>(Colors.Green, COLORCODE2));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Regards,
Nico

PS: I haven't compiled nor tested this code.